# Radio box question to linking based on states

Tags: css

so im making a form but i dont know how to likelink it to a differnt webpage using the state of the radio boxes,
so like if this is checked then go here if its not then go ther

```
<label for="choose">choose</label>
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="1" href="1.html">2
      <input type="radio" name="2" value="2" href="2.html">2
```

so i tried using this but it wont work

Comment: `input` elements to not have a `href` attribute.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to achieve here - do you want to submit a form these radios are in, to different target URLs, based on the radio selection? Or do you want to redirect to the selected URL _after_ you processed form data at a static target URL? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

In `input` we can't use `href`, but instead we can use `data-target`, and then, to make it work, a bit of a JQuery, like so:

```js
 $(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
      var item = $(this);    
      if(item.is(":checked")) {
        window.open(item.data("target"), "_blank"); //the later is the target frame
      }    
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="choose">choose</label>
<input type="radio" data-target="1.html" name="1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" data-target="2.html" name="1" value="2"/>
```